# Which ASIO channels in Mumble map to what in VoiceMeeter?

Tags: voip, game-development, voice-recording

I'm attempting to pass my microphone through "Voicemeeter Virtual Audio Mixer" for use with Mumble. Reasons for doing this: 1. to colour the audio, 2. to support recording in Audacity while still using a low-latency driver for Mumble. (other drivers either take control of the audio device so Audacity cannot access it, or appear to introduce significant latency) I would like to record just my audio, and in high quality (not just what mumble would record with its built-in recording).

The audio output from Mumble also must go to Voicemeeter as both input and output must be the same device when using the ASIO option in Mumble (as far as I can tell).

Mumble shows VoiceMeeter's virtual ASIO ports simple as "VM-VAIO 1" through "VM-VAIO 8", so I have no idea what is what. Choosing the wrong option for Microphone and Speaker causes Mumble to crash so trial and error is tedious (And you need to pick both a speaker and a microphone channel to Apply the settings).

Is there a right option? What do VM-VAIO 1 thru 8 map to in VoiceMeeter? I can't find anything on their site other than they have say there is "8 channel virtual input" (with 4 as ASIO) and ditto for output.

[image: Mumble ASIO settings for VoiceMeeter]
Mumble ASIO settings for VoiceMeeter

[image: Where is VM-VAIO 1, VM-VAIO 2, VM-VAIO 3, etc?]
Where is VM-VAIO 1, VM-VAIO 2, VM-VAIO 3, etc?

[image: Picked the wrong numbers Microphone and Speaker. Or will this happen with all options?]
Picked the wrong numbers Microphone and Speaker. Or will this happen with all options?

Software and hardware: Mumble 1.2.8, VoiceMeeter 1.0.3.6, Windows 8.1 64-bit, Roland DUO-Capture EX.

Answer (score 1):

Voicemeeter Virtual ASIO Device is connected to Virtual Input Strip (ch 1 = Front Left, ch 2 = Front right, ch 3 = Center, ch 4 = LFE... ). Voicemeeter AUX ASIO Device is connected to second virtual input (of Voicemeeter Banana). User Manual and video tutorial are available on web page www.voicemeeter.com